# modernizr - how to

Tags: modernizr

Hi I am testing modernizr and this is the code i did and i am not able to see the styles in the html tag in view source, does any one know why ???

```
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>content</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you view source you are viewing the actual source code of the file *as downloaded*, not after the script has executed (at least in modern browsers, I seem to remember that IE6 somehow showed source based on the live DOM).

If you use something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can see the live source, including the classes on the `html` element.

Comment: Good to hear ;-) Please remember to mark my answer as correct.